# How to prevent duplicate documents mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a user collection and a portfolio collection on mongodb. The portfolio model references the objectid of the users collection. I'm trying to make it so when a user is logged in, and they try to add document they already have, the router prevents it. Right now all this does is look through all the documents in the portfolio collection but I'm trying to filter it by users first, then search the name to see if it's there.

```
  portfolio.find({name: req.body.name})
  .count()
  .then(count => {
    if (count > 0) {
      // There is an existing user with the same username
      res.status(400).json({message: 'Stock already saved!'});
    }else{
     portfolio
     .create({
       user: req.body.user,
       name: req.body.name,
       description: req.body.description,
       symbol: req.body.symbol,
       image: req.body.image,
     })
     .then(portfolioPost => res.status(201).json(portfolioPost.serialize()))
     .catch(err => {
       // console.error(err);
       res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
     });
    }
  })
```

this is the model

```
const listSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Users" },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: {type:String, required: true},
  image: {type:String},
  symbol: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

Comment: Its not clear from your question what are you trying to ask- review of the code or resolution of an error you are getting or reason if above code is not working?

Answer (score -1):

Use **{ unique: true }**  So, whenever anyone tries to use same user id to multiple portfolios, the mongoose will throw an error.

Your model will be then,

```
const listSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Users", unique: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: {type:String, required: true},
  image: {type:String},
  symbol: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

I used the **user** properties **unique**. So no two list schema can have the same userId.

Finally, you can skip finding previous user portfolio. Your code can be

```
portfolio
     .create({
       user: req.body.user,
       name: req.body.name,
       description: req.body.description,
       symbol: req.body.symbol,
       image: req.body.image,
     })
     .then(portfolioPost => res.status(201).json(portfolioPost.serialize()))
     .catch(err => {
       // console.error(err);
       res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
     });
```

In this case, if there already a portfolio with the current userId, the MongoDB will be sent an error.

For more details, please check the [Additional Options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html) section.

Comment: This won't help as unique key is to create unique indices in the mongodb not to check the duplication of the data as validation part before saving it.